# Install Ubuntu next to Windows 7 with a 3rd partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

I would like to install Ubuntu next to Windows 7. I've got a 256GB SSD in my Laptop and I would like to create three 'main' partitions:

- about 50GB for the Ubuntu System
- about 50GB for the Windows System
- about 150GB for my files to be accessible from both systems.

How do I create these partitions when installing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS? Which file-systems do I need to choose so that the large partition is accessible for both operating systems?

Thanks for your help in advance

Jurg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Boot Ubuntu live disk and choose "try ubuntu" option on startup.
- Open gparted.Create three partitions as you mentioned above(ext4 partition for Ubuntu os,ntfs partition for Windows Os and another ntfs partition(150) for storing datas which was accessed by the both.
- Then run the Ubuntu installer and choose "something else" option to install Ubuntu on the created ext4 partition.